SignalR connection through Azure APIM
The Situation
I am using azure apim to proxy requests from client to my web app backend. I am succesfully forwarding the requests through the apim, mainly to hide my backend url in the request from the client. So just to expose the proxy url. However i am struggling with forwarding the signalR connection request through my Azure APIM. I need to do this because the negotiation handshake exposes my backendurl since im directly requesting the backend hub endpoint.
The attempted solution
I've tried following this tutorial with LongPolling / ServerSentEvents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-work-with-apim.




I've also added the APIM as a ClientEndpoint in the connection string that i use in my backend.

Any pointers whatsoever would be appreciated, seems like a niche problem and cannot really find any similar problems on the internet. Also any other solutions other than going through APIM would also be great!
Thank you.

Did you ever get this working?


I believe, you are trying to invoke the incorrect Url, hence getting 404. If you have followed all the steps given in LongPolling / ServerSentEvents doc then your Url should look like POST https://{apimInstance}.azure-api.net/client/negotiate?hub=chatsamplehub.
I have created all the given operations in APIM and then generated the connection string by providing the Url of APIM in client endpoint field.
I have below code in index.html file.

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("/chat",
      { transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents  })
  .build();


I have below operations in APIM.



I am invoke the APIM negotiate operation as shown below.



How does the javascript client know the URL of the reverse proxy in this case? When running locally my javascript client is using localhost as opposed to the actual APIM URL. What should the full URL be when specified in the client?
